# exc_bad_exception during CFRelease

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a code line this and I get a crash consistently on line mentioned below.

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
    ABRecordRef source = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, kABPersonSortByFirstName);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
    for (...) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
        ...
        CFRelease(persn)
    }
    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(allPeople);
    CFRelease(addressBook);
```

I consistently get the error on the last line `CFRelease(addressBook);`
. However,

if I remove line `CFRelease(person)` inside the for loop, then I stopped getting bad access error on last line

Would you know why is that the case?

What are the possible candidates for CFRelease in above code and why???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needn't to release person.

ABAddressBook**Create**WithOptions -> need

ABAddressBook**Copy**DefaultSource -> need

CFArray**Get**ValueAtIndex -> needn't

Once you release **allPeople**, all **person** will be release.